# Replacing JSON string with another string in java

Tags: java, json

```
String str = "{"id":"4ebd7e4f","start_page_ui_id":"","business_unit":["5b65aced"],"props":{"metadata":"[]","postsPerPage":"20","network_id":"1b375ffd"},"render_engine":"twig"}"
```

Here I want to replace "metadata":"[]" to "metadata":"["key":"value,value1","key1":"value2"]"

for this i tried to replace as

```
str =str.replace("\"metadata\":\"[\"", "\"metadata\": \"[{\"key\":\"key\",\"val\":\"value,value1\"},{\"key\":\"key1\",\"val\":\"value2\"}");
```

But it is not getting replaced. I don't understand why??
Can any one please help me to solve this issue.

I want to replace another string "postsPerPage":"20" to "postsPerPage":"6"

for this i tried with

```
str = str .replace("\"postsPerPage\": \"20\",", "\"postsPerPage\": \"9\",");
```

Here also the value is not changing.

Comment: why are you not using json classes to this?

Comment: What is your json parser , what library ?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/). You can then reassign values in your Java object, before converting it back to JSON with your desired output.

Comment: The content was in a Json format. I have used toString() method to convert into string. After converting it into string I was trying to replace.

Comment: That is not a long term solution and is bound to get unwieldy in the near future and is also known as a shortcut! Lol its your choice how you do it, but maintainable and understandable is the better way out!

Comment: `ParseJson(str).getAsArray("metadata").add(...)` would be enough. (the method name are for show of course). Use any Json API, it will be MUCH EASIER.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON third-party lib for this, [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) being the most popular ones.

For example with GSON (only for small samples! for large blobs of JSON you should consider using the stream API):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String str = "{\"id\":\"4ebd7e4f\",\"start_page_ui_id\":\"\",\"business_unit\":[\"5b65aced\"],\"props\":{\"metadata\":\"[]\",\"postsPerPage\":\"20\",\"network_id\":\"1b375ffd\"},\"render_engine\":\"twig\"}";
        String metadataReplacementJson = "[{\"key\":\"key\",\"val\":\"value,value1\"},{\"key\":\"key1\",\"val\":\"value2\"}]";
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(str, JsonObject.class);

        jsonObject
                .get("props")
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .remove("metadata");

        jsonObject
                .get("props")
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .add("metadata", gson.fromJson(metadataReplacementJson, JsonArray.class));

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonObject));
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
{"id":"4ebd7e4f","start_page_ui_id":"","business_unit":["5b65aced"],"props":{"metadata":[{"key":"key","val":"value,value1"},{"key":"key1","val":"value2"}],"postsPerPage":"20","network_id":"1b375ffd"},"render_engine":"twig"}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Anyway you might try removing the property first - see the updated answer

Comment: Also what GSON version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Rather a lengthy process, I will outline here what you need to do inorder to manuplate your JSON.

- Create a POJO for your JSON.
- Parse your JSON and create a POJO Object.
- Now manipulate the POJO Object with your new data (Update values, replace etc..)
- Write back the fresh JSON.

Libraries: GSON, Jackson are of help here. You can also use online JSON to POJO converters to make your task even more easier.

Comment: The POJO is not strictly necessary, you can use the JSON tree objects returned by your JSON library directly. But yes, definitely use a JSON parser, don't work on Strings.

Comment: @Thilo Yes I agree, GSON and Jackson being the best ones so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace with

```
"\"metadata\":\"["
```

not

```
"\"metadata\":\"[\""
```

and

```
"\"postsPerPage\": \"20\","
```

should be

```
"\"postsPerPage\":\"20\""
```

Answer (score 0):

> **String objects are immutable**, so whenever we perform any operation in
>   existing string object at that time a new string object is created.The
>   new Stirng object is not assign to any any String object.

so str = str .replace("\"postsPerPage\": \"20\",", "\"postsPerPage\": \"9\",");

In above line created new object it is automatically eligible for garbage collection.

> String str2 = str .replace("\"postsPerPage\": \"20\",",
>   "\"postsPerPage\": \"9\",");

here new String object created. str2 is point to String object.

now you can use str2 will work.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested, java 21 has introduced an STR Template

```
STR."Invalid order quantity : \{qty}";
```

[image]